# wkhtmltopdf as node module fails when run as windows service

Tags: node.js, windows-services, wkhtmltopdf

I am running a node app that uses the wkhtmltopdf module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/wkhtmltopdf) and node routing to return a pdf of a page when the user navigates to a /pdf path. Everything works fine when the app is run on in the servers console, but when the app runs as a Windows service, the pdf call fails. I get the browser crash screen with the message that the site refused to connect. The rest of the site works fine, just the path to return PDFs fails, and I can't glean anything from the logs. Is this a known issue with wkhtmltopdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OS: Fedora
I had the issue with my node server program and wkhtmltopdf module in it, not generating pdf when run as a service. Turns out that a user for the service was set as nobody and so was usergroup. We removed that entry and reran the service it works.

I am guessing this could be the issue with Windows as well.

Please let me know if it did not work, did work or you already solved the problem with another approach.

Comment: Yes, we eventually figured out that it was a user issues. Thanks